# Xcode 12 Interface Builder is showing “No selection”

Tags: swift, interface-builder, xcode12

Recently updated my Xcode to 12.0.1 and now my interface builder is messed up. It says No Selection for every View Controller. Restarted Xcode but still the problem exists.

[A screenshot of how my Interface Builder looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sO9Ac.png)

Comment: I had this issue too, but restart Xcode fix for me

Comment: but not in my case :/

Comment: try some other methods like clean project, delete derived data..., maybe it helps

Comment: try to restart your Mac, it's silly but sometimes fixing a lot of problems with internal XCode references. Also, try to create a new `Storyboard` and try to create new `UIViewController` and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try delete derived data
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: i have tried it but still i am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I closed xcode and opened it again and it worked, before i tried closing my tabs for storyboard and launch screen, they both had the same bug but then i just restarted xcode.

Comment: This seems to be an XCode Bug. This instantly started to nerf me after the last Update... Deleting DerrivedData folder does not help, but restarting what they call IDE works.

Answer (score 1):

MOST SIMPLE SOLUTION:

(For each of those who has tried all the above options like me, try this once):

Switch to the LaunchScreen.storyboard from your Main.storyboard
See if you can access all the Inspectors on right side in LaunchScreen.storyboard .
if yes,
Switch back to Main.storyboard
Always work for me! Hope this also help to someone. Thanks!

EDIT 1:

Above solution works for xib only projects too.